# How can I open a 2nd session in "remote" desktop from the console to the local machine?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, terminal-services

**Context**

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise developer machine. Sitting in front of this machine I would like to open an RDP session to this machine and logging on as a test user.

**Question**

When I try to open an RDP session to 127.0.0.1 I got the message (see attached picture). I understand the message, still I would like to accomplish my goal if it is possible at all. How can I workaround this and have a 2nd "remote" session with a test user?

[image]

Comment: You cannot. The only way you can do this, is by using a Virtual Machine, and RDP into the Virtual Machine.

Comment: client version don't allow concurrent logins (only server windows versions), but there are unofficial patches to hack this.